# fatal: repository does not exist when cloning shared repository

Tags: linux, git, rhel

I'm trying to create a shared bare repository from an existing project so that multiple developers within the same group can have access. I have cloned the repository located in my project's directory to a bare shared repository in another centralized directory on the same machine and am able to create a clone of bare repo myself, however the clone fails with a fatal: repository does not exist error when logged in as another user within the group.

I've tried following the instructions on the git website for creating a bare repository and for cloning a repository.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Based on the instructions, I used the following commands to create the bare repository and make it shared.

```
$ git clone --bare /path/to/my_dir/my_project /path/to/repos/project.git
$ cd /path/to/repos/project.git
$ git init --bare --shared
```

I am able to successfully make a clone using the following commands when I'm logged in as myself.

```
$ cd /path/to/their_dir
$ git clone /path/to/repos/project.git their_project
```

However, when logged in as a different user, the following error occurs when trying to use the same commands, even though I can do an ls on and cd into the project.git directory as the other user.

```
fatal: repository '/path/to/repos/project.git' does not exist
```

As far as permissions go, my account is listed as the owner of the repository and it's files, and the other user belongs to the group that is associated with the files.

```
$ ls -l /path/to/repos
drwxrws---. 6 me devs 4096 Jul 24 12:53 project.git

$ ls -l /path/to/repos/project.git
drwx------.   2 me devs 4096 Jul 24 12:46 branches
-rw-rw----.   1 me devs  177 Jul 24 12:53 config
-rw-------.   1 me devs   73 Jul 24 12:46 description
-rw-------.   1 me devs   23 Jul 24 12:46 HEAD
drwx------.   2 me devs 4096 Jul 24 12:52 hooks
drwx------.   2 me devs 4096 Jul 24 12:46 info
drwx------. 104 me devs 4096 Jul 24 12:46 objects
-rw-------.   1 me devs   98 Jul 24 12:46 packed-refs
drwxrws---.   4 me devs 4096 Jul 24 12:46 refs
```

How can I fix this so that another user can clone the repository while logged in under his or her account?

Comment: Are all directories in the path accessible to the group of the second user? (i.e. `g+x`?) – I also notice that most files in your `project.git` directory are not readable by the group (`g-rwx`). Make sure the permissions are correct (they might require manual fixing)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked. I modified the permissions of the files in the project.git directory to give the group rwx permissions for all of the directories and rw permissions for all of the files. However, when I push updates from my_project, the newly added hashes under the objects directory don't retain those permissions (the user and group only have read permissions). Are the write permissions necessary in this case?

Comment: Files under `.git/objects` will never be rewritten, that's okay. The only thing that might happen is that they will be deleted after a GC (lookup `git gc` and `git repack`)